# Feedburner doesn't work anymore

Tags: feedburner

I really have no idea how to figure out what exactly is wrong and so I'm seeking help here.

When I try to validate my feed I get the following error message:

```
    XML parsing error: <unknown>:8:17928: mismatched tag
... d/show_ads.js">/*<![CDATA[*/<p>/*]]>*/</script></div><p>The next day I h ...
```

The source is the original feed URL, not Feedburner itself, of course.
The .js is from Google Adsense that I have implemented in my blog posts recently.

I also get this:

```
In addition, interoperability with the widest range of feed readers could be improved by implementing the following recommendation.

    line 1, column 485: Self reference doesn't match document location [help]

        ... rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" /><link>http://zoomingjapan.com</l ...
```

Source here is Feedburner itself.

What I did so far is that I removed Adsense almost completely from my blog.
The feed recovered partly. At first no latest posts were shown in the feed at all.
Now they're shown again: http://feeds.feedburner.com/ZoomingJapan
So, it seems to have to do with Adsense or it's just all a huge coincidence.

However, what I still don't understand is why the usual Feedburner layout isn't showing up, the the typical RSS Feed Layout instead. Something seems to be going wrong there!

Can anybody tell me what exactly is wrong and what I need to do to fix this problem?
Let me know if you need any additional information.

Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Feedburner and AdSense don't work well together any more.  Google is progressively shutting that down.  You can read about it in their [official "Spring Cleaning" announcement](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2012/09/more-spring-cleaning.html).

But also, you likely have a major issue with your site in general.  This is what I see when I try to visit your blog page:

[image: Error Page]

---

Now that your site is working, I was able to load your *raw* feed to see what's going on with it.  The crux of the issue is that your feed - the XML being served from your site, not Feedburner - is broken.  Feedburner then tries to parse this broken data and churns out junk itself.  Garbage in, garbage out.

I've copied the raw XML your site is presenting in response to requests to http://zoomingjapan.com/blog/feed/ to a Gist: https://gist.github.com/3880465

The issue is, it's ***not valid XML*** ... the document starts out OK:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<rss version="2.0" 
     xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" 
     xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/" 
     xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" 
     xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" 
     xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/" 
     xmlns:slash="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/" >
    <channel>
        <title>Zooming Japan &#187; Blog</title> 
        <atom:link href="http://zoomingjapan.com/blog/feed/" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
        <link>http://zoomingjapan.com</link>
        <description></description> 
        <lastBuildDate>Wed, 10 Oct 2012 15:03:55 +0000</lastBuildDate> 
        <language>en-US</language> 
...
```

But every XML validator I run your feed through complains about the `<script>` tags littered through your content.  In reality, you shouldn't have `<script>` tags in content to begin with - they belong in the `<head>` element of your page.

Comment: Still? I thought we took care of that already: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53630/w3-cache-plugin-and-facebook-sharing ....
Any idea what I could do to get rid of that cryptic problem .... jeez :/

Thanks a lot for your answer.
Does that mean I can't use a proper working feed anymore as long as I implement Google Adsense?

Comment: Sorry, actually it was this one here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/59309/page-output-in-strange-characters-uncompressed-gzip

Comment: I tried everything I could. I can't reproduce the problem you are reporting and thus I can't fix it.
Is it somehow possible for your to try and help me despite of that? I edited my question, too.
It should be possible to fix the feed somehow without removing Adsense, right?

Comment: see my update...

Comment: Thanks so much!
I usually never put javascript in my content directly, but I thought for Adsense there's no other option and I also wanted to be able to choose for each blog entry where I put the ad to see what works best. That's why I didn't hardcode it into the single.php.
What other options do I have if I want to keep Adsense in my content?

Comment: All the tutorials about Adsense I can find online just say that you place the code as is into your content. None of them says that it has caused them any problems.
Don't you think the problem is caused by something else?
I see so many blogs that have Adsense in their blog post content AND a working feed.

Comment: The problem *could* be caused by something else, but every tool I can use to check your feed for problems is complaining about the `<script>` tags specifically. For debugging purposes, remove them and see if that fixes the issue. If not, it will at least give you then another error message upon validation so you can continue tracking things down.

Comment: I removed all Adsense Codes in my blog posts and now the original feed as well as the Feedburner feed are valid feeds and the Feedburner layout shows properly anymore.
However, I want to be able to use Adsense in my blog posts without giving up on the functionality of my RSS feed.
Is there a way? I've seen people using Adsense AND Feedburner without any issues!

Comment: Please [ask a *new* question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) along these lines. This current thread is getting long and won't help future visitors.